# Taking single columns of data and exporting to multiple columns in separate CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell-3.0

I recently created a PowerShell script to gather disk size, usage and free space, then export them into a CSV. Now I need to create a new CSV file with the "free space" column of each created file. I need to have each column grabbed, dropped into a new column. I've been tinkering with a script and digging into articles all day without luck. Below is the closest I've gotten.

```bsh
$sort = gci | select name | Where-Object {$_.name -like "diskspace_*"}
$count = 0
foreach ($item in $sort) {
    $count = ($count +=1)
    $free = Import-Csv $item.name | Select-Object 'Free'
    $share = Import-Csv $item.name |
             Select-Object 'Share',@{Name="something"; Expression={$free.free}} |
             Export-Csv free_report.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the target CSV is supposed to look like. Please provide samples for input and desired output.

Comment: so the input is going to be (col1 - col4) from several csv files all formatted the same way. I am taking columns 1 and 3 ('Shares' and 'Free Space') from each. The output I would like is ('Shares', 'Free Space from csv1', 'Free Space from csv2', etc.) . Importing the original 2 columns is easy, but telling it to take the 'Free Space' column from additional csv files and adding them to append to their own column has been nightmare fuel so far.